# BDD with Specflow using selenium

Tags: bdd, specflow

When i create a project and i try to add a feature file, feature file gets created without designer code(i.e a .cs file is not getting created)All the tags "Given ,when, then , Scenario" is not getting recognized.
Which .dll are getting are missed, can somebody help me on this??

Answer (score 1):

You need the SpecFlow NuGet package.